# Extract and convert blob field in image. MySQL - Java

Tags: java, mysql, image, blob, fingerprint

I am writing a java program for fingerprint recognition, and I insert the fingerprint image in the MySQL database( in a field blob), but now is the problem. 
How do I go back to the image of the fingerprint? where I have to print it?( I presume in a canvas). help me please is very important, thanks to all.

Comment: do you have any code already that you can show us?

Answer (score 1):

The blob is a array of bytes, so is the Image.

So

```
img -> read bytes -> store as blob
```

vs

```
blob -> read bytes -> store as img
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but could you explain in detail how to do? I'm not very handy thanks.